# Pandas - for loop and find index that has the nearest value

Tags: python, pandas

I am basically trying to loop through a dataframe that has been grouped and finding the index that has the nearest value to the input argument.

For example, given the dataframe below, for every group defined by the `global_id`, I want to group to take frames that are spaced at least 10 frames apart. For example if I have a list of frames [1,2,3,4,14,20,30,31], the output would be [1,14,30] because

- I would initialize by taking frame 1 as the first frame
- The next frame that is at least 10 frames apart would be frame number 14
- The following frame that is at least 10 frame apart from 14 is 30

As such, the resulting before and after dataframe should look like below

Before:

```
       seq_name     label pedestrian_id  frame_no  global_id
0          0001  crossing          0001  0001         1
1          0001  crossing          0001  0002         1
2          0001  crossing          0001  0003         1
3          0001  crossing          0001  0004         1
4          0001  crossing          0001  0005         1
5          0001  crossing          0001  0006         1
6          0001  crossing          0001  0007         1
7          0001  crossing          0001  0008         1
8          0001  crossing          0001  0009         1
9          0001  crossing          0001  0010         1
10         0001  crossing          0002  0001         2
11         0001  crossing          0002  0012         2
12         0001  crossing          0002  0013         2
13         0001  crossing          0002  0014         2
14         0001  crossing          0002  0015         2
15         0001  crossing          0002  0029         2
16         0001  crossing          0002  0030         2
17         0001  crossing          0002  0031         2
18         0001  crossing          0002  0032         2
19         0001  crossing          0002  0033         2
20         0002  crossing          0001  0034         3
21         0002  crossing          0001  0035         3
22         0002  crossing          0001  0036         3
23         0002  crossing          0001  0037         3
24         0002  crossing          0001  0038         3
25         0002  crossing          0001  0039         3
26         0002  crossing          0001  0049         3
27         0002  crossing          0001  0050         3
28         0002  crossing          0001  0051         3
29         0002  crossing          0001  0052         3
```

After filter:

```
       seq_name     label pedestrian_id  frame_no  global_id
0          0001  crossing          0001  0001         1
10         0001  crossing          0002  0001         2
11         0001  crossing          0002  0012         2
15         0001  crossing          0002  0029         2
25         0002  crossing          0001  0039         3
26         0002  crossing          0001  0049         3
```

Below is what I have. Once I have the indices I can create a new dataframe by indexing from the old. I am still new to Pandas and it looks extremely cumbersome so I am hoping there is a more elegant solution.

I have read through the docs on groupby and some other SO posts but still can't figure it out. I am just trying to clean up my data processing pipeline by replacing everything with Pandas.

```
ind = []
for j in df["global_id"].unique():
    df_temp = df[df["global_id"] == j][["frame_no"]]
    df_temp["frame_no"] = pd.to_numeric(df["frame_no"]) 
    start_frame = df_temp["frame_no"].min()
    end_frame = df_temp["frame_no"].max()
    i = start_frame-1
    while i < end_frame:
        ind.append(np.min(df_temp[(df_temp["frame_no"] > i) & (df_temp["frame_no"] < i+10)].index.tolist()))
        i+=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `groupby` but first you need to define a function doing what you look for in each group. To explain the idea, let's consider a simple dataframe `dfs = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,14,20,30,31]})`

I have been looking to solve this kind of problem for a while, trying to avoid looping and it seems complex. Here is the idea I end up with. In numpy, you can use `substract` combined with `outer` to get all the differences between each element one to one

```
print (np.subtract.outer(dfs.a, dfs.a))
array([[  0,  -1,  -2,  -3, -13, -19, -29, -30],
       [  1,   0,  -1,  -2, -12, -18, -28, -29],
       [  2,   1,   0,  -1, -11, -17, -27, -28],
       [  3,   2,   1,   0, -10, -16, -26, -27],
       [ 13,  12,  11,  10,   0,  -6, -16, -17],
       [ 19,  18,  17,  16,   6,   0, -10, -11],
       [ 29,  28,  27,  26,  16,  10,   0,  -1],
       [ 30,  29,  28,  27,  17,  11,   1,   0]], dtype=int64)
```

Now, for example, in `column 0`, you can see that difference `>10` start at `row 4`, then going to `column 4`, difference `>10` start at `row 6` and going to `column 6` you don't get a difference big enough. So the filtering would be keeping row 0, 4 and 6, which is the values [1,14,30] as looking for. To get these numbers, you can compare the `np.substract.outer` to 10 and `sum` over the `axis=0` such as:

```
arr = (np.subtract.outer(dfs.a, dfs.a) <=10).sum(0)
print (arr)
array([4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8])
```

Now you see, `arr[0] = 4`, then `arr[4] = 6`, then `arr[6]=8` is out of bound in this example so stop. One way to catch these number is using a `while` (if someone has a `numpy` solution to do this, I'm interested in)

```
list_ind = [0] # initialize list of index to keep with 0
arr = (np.subtract.outer(dfs.a, dfs.a) <=10).sum(0)
i = arr[0]
while i < len(arr):
    list_ind.append(i)
    i = arr[i]

print (list_ind)
[0, 4, 6]

print (dfs.iloc[list_ind])
    a
0   1
4  14
6  30
```

Now with the whole problem and `groupby`, you can do:

```
# it seems you need to convert the column frame_no to integer
df['frame_int'] = pd.to_numeric(df['frame_no'])
df = df.sort_values('frame_int') #ensure data to be sorted by frame_int, whatever the global_id

#define the function looking for the ind
def find_ind (df_g):
    list_ind = [0]
    arr = (np.subtract.outer(df_g.frame_int, df_g.frame_int) <= 10).sum(0)
    i = arr[0]
    while i <len(arr):
        list_ind.append(i)
        i = arr[i]
    return df_g.iloc[list_ind]

#create the filtered dataframe
df_filtered = (df.groupby('global_id').apply(find_ind)
                 .drop('frame_int',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))

print (df_filtered)
   seq_name     label  pedestrian_id  frame_no  global_id
0         1  crossing              1         1          1
1         1  crossing              2         1          2
2         1  crossing              2        12          2
3         1  crossing              2        29          2
4         2  crossing              1        34          3
5         2  crossing              1        49          3
```

If you want to keep the original rows' index, you can add `level=0` in `reset_index` such as  `reset_index(level=0,drop=True)` instead.